# How can you tell if a trigger is enabled in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, triggers, status

This shouldn't be hard to do. I'd expect Enterprise Manager to show a folder of trigger and a list and an icon... but I don't see it anywhere. My google results get me answers where I have to write code. Are you kidding me? The only way is by writing code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT
CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('trigger name goes here'), 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
WHEN 0 THEN 'ENABLED'
ELSE 'DISABLED'
END
```

Answer (score 5):

This query will return all triggers and their status as well as what table the trigger is for.

```
SELECT
 so1.name as TriggerName, 
 CASE 
  OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(so1.name), 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
  WHEN 0 THEN 'ENABLED'
  ELSE 'DISABLED'
 END AS Status,
 so2.Name as TableName
FROM 
 SysObjects so1
 JOIN SysObjects so2
  ON so2.Id = so1.Parent_obj
WHERE 
 so1.type = 'TR'
```

Answer (score 4):

In Enterprise Manager drill down through databases -> and select tables

In the details pane, right click on the table in question and select 'Manage Triggers' and voila! You should be able to find what you're looking for in there.

Comment: This answer actually answers the question asked. The accepted answer uses code. I'm confused...